# Reading an XML and fetching values in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

What is the cleanest way to be able to fetch the values of Name, Offset and Length as many as they are in this XML using c#

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RecordLayout>
  <Field>
    <Name>Ali</Name>
    <Offset>1</Offset>
    <Length>2</Length>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <Offset>1</Offset>
    <Length>2</Length>
  </Field>
</RecordLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx) it can be done like this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

var elements = xmlDocument
              .Root
              .Elements("Field")
              .Select(x => new
              {
                  Name = (string) x.Element("Name"),
                  Offset = (int) x.Element("Offset"),
                  Length = (int) x.Element("Length")
              });
```

Comment: OK and now how do I fetch those values?

Comment: @UserAnonymous what are you asking? you already fetch the values ? add ToList after the query if you want to get them into a list

Comment: Hi Another question , if there is another XML that nly has Name and not Offset nor Length , can this query be used to give you the same List of names in elements ?